# Help with Eclipse line wrapping

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to get something like:

```
someObject.firstFunctionCall().secondFunctionCall().thirdFunctionCall();
```

to look like:

```
someObject.firstFunctionCall()  
          .secondFunctionCall()  
          .thirdFunctionCall()
```

I played around with the formatting editor and tried searching to no avail. I just can't think of the name for multiple function calls in one statement. I can do it myself but then it reverts to the top example every time I run the formatter.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to format it yourself.

To configure the formatter to not rewrap already wrapped lines, you can select this option in the "Line Wrapping" section of the formatter:

- Never join already wrapped lines

Though it will change the indentation of the two lines.